# Server public key in server key exchange message EAP-TLS

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, wireshark

I receive this EAP-TLS fragment from a RADIUS server:

[image]

I received this packet in a uint8_t array in C, and when I compared the bits with the public key enclosed in this message, I found that all of them were different. This led me to believe that the public key has been encrypted. If so, how is it encrypted and what can I do to retrieve the public key ? Is  it related to the signature (256 bit) enclosed after the pubkey ? I need it to complete the DH parameter generation on both sides.

Thank you!

Comment: Where's the difference? At least 8 of the bytes look the same to me.

Comment: How do you receive them in C? Is there a byte network ordering issue?

Comment: The difference is in the pubkey and the signature, ie the EC Diffie-Hellman Server Params, yes some of them are the same, but most of them are different. I receive them in C using raw sockets, and I don't believe that it is a byte ordering issue because the rest of the bytes are perfect

Answer (score 0):

> I received this packet in a uint8_t array in C, and when I compared the bits with the public key enclosed in this message, I found that all of them were different.

The server's public key `B` (which is `g ^ b`) *should* be different on each run of the protocol. If you are seeing repeating values, then something is wrong. See [RFC 4492](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4492#page-19), Page 18:

> public: The ephemeral ECDH public key

"ephemeral" means temporary, and its used once and then thrown away.

---

> how is it encrypted and what can I do to retrieve the public key

Its not encrypted; its a temporary key that's used once.

---

> Is it related to the signature (256 bit) enclosed after the pubkey ?

No.

---

OpenSSL has a wiki page on Elliptic Curve Cryptography. See [Elliptic Curve Cryptography](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Elliptic_Curve_Cryptography).

Comment: I think you misunderstood my problem, I copied the contents of this same packet to a uint8_t[] array, and I printed out the contents of the array. When I compare each individual index, I see that they are different from what I see in Wireshark. Thank you for clearing the signature part though

Comment: So I'm clear: you asked a Wireshark copy/paste question on a programming site? Sigh....

Comment: My question is, why is the content of the packet I received over the wire different from the one Wireshark is showing. I don't know if this is a copy/paste question